# Products of Positive Matrices

Tags: matrices, ergodic-theory, contraction-operator

Is it true that every infinite product of positive matrices (every element is larger than 0) converges to a rank one matrix?

I learned that Birkhoff's Contraction Coefficient is smaller than one for positive matrices and that Birkhoff's Contraction Coefficient is submultiplicative.

Additionally, Birkhoff's Contraction Coefficient is 0 for rank 1 matrices.

Combining these insights, the claim should follow.
But it is somehow against my intuition.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Birkhoff's Contraction Coefficient is 0 for rank 1 matrices." Is this statement an "if and only if"?

Comment: No, it's only "If the coefficient is 0, the matrix has rank 1"

Comment: Are you asking whether for any positive matrix $A$ such that the sequence of powers $A^k$ converges, $A^k$ tends to a rank-one matrix? Or are you asking whether for any positive matrices $A_j$, the product $A_1A_2\dots A_k$ converges to a rank-one matrix (if it converges)?

Comment: My question is: If I take an infinite sequence of positive matrices and multiply them ; does the product of these matrix sequence converge to a  matrix of rank 1?

Comment: Of course not, if the matrices are arbitrary. The question makes sense with powers of a positive matrix. Check out the Perron-Frobenius theorem for stochastic matrices, maybe that is what you are looking for.

Comment: That's also my intuition. Maybe I misinterpret the coefficient. Does anyone know the coefficient?

Comment: I do not understand the question. What happens if all the matrices you multiply are the identity? You get the identity, not a rank one matrix

Comment: The identity matrix is not a positive matrix